# Display a product attribute on orders page in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, product, order-grid

I am using this custom module https://bitbucket.org/vovsky/adding-custom-product-attribute-to-quote-and-order-items-in/downloads related article https://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

which allows a custom attribute to be added when adding products

when this product is purchased it stores the numerical data entered in this attribute to mage_sales_flat_order

Unfortunately it doesnt show up anywhere on the order info?
How would I display this on the admin panel order summary page or on the individual order page?

Comment: I am using this module for extra fees https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee

In the checkout page extra fees field displayed and applied in grand total everything okay, in the order page the extra fees field not visible, the grand total applied with extra fees but extra fees column not visible, any help thanks.

The only issue is extra field column not visible on backend?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to edit the template file directly. Depending on where exactly on the order page you want it displayed, but it would be in this folder:

```
 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/
```

The most common one is in `info.phtml`. You will see at the top, it instantiates the `$_order` object, so anywhere in the file you can just call `$_order->getData('my_custom_attribute')`

Comment: /sales/item/column/name.phtml tried adding  <?php echo $_order->getData('custom_attribute') ?> and as you suggested  <?php echo $_order->getData('my_custom_attribute') ?>  and it breaks the page sorry I am truely a novice to this

Comment: This template renders every item line, so it natively doesn't load the order there but if you shove `$_order = Mage::registry('current_order');` it should then work. Although it will display the same information on every line, since this attribute is assigned to the order.

Comment: Although, reading your original question, it's a big ambiguous. Not sure if the attribute is on the order, or on the order item. If the latter, just use `$_item->getData('my_custom_attribute')` (obviously replace 'my_custom_attribute' with the attribute code you want to display)

Comment: upon installing this custom module it adds a field to the add/edit product for Custom_Attribute aka custom_attribute in my case is being used as profit margin data so each product has a different profit margin amount not sure where its storing the data however i do see a column in  mage_sales_flat_order for the Custom_Attribute however it is not displaying the data that was entered when i edit the product not sure where it was being stored. i would assume the product order item?

Comment: mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar   I added "matchthis" to the product field and found this in the sql at mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar 
Value ID
entity_type_id
Entity Type ID
attribute_id
Attribute ID
store_id
Store ID
entity_id
Entity ID
value
Value

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
160305
4
204
0
38
matchthis

Comment: value ='s "matchthis" so i guess the question is what code do i paste into what file to display that info for each item order on the order summary on the admin side only ofcourse :) so each item will display that data that i will set when adding items

Answer (score 1):

You may add custom admin theme to display an extra product attribute at order, shipment and invoice views at once: 

`config.xml:`

```
<config>
<!-- other -->
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <template>custom</template>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Then copy `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml` into `app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml` and fetch your attribute:

```
<?php if ($customAttr = $_item->getProduct()->getCustomAttr()):?>
    <?php $attrLabel = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
        ->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'custom_attr')
        ->getFrontendLabel()
?>
    <dl class="item-options"><dt><?php echo $attrLabel ?></dt><dd><?php echo $customAttr ?></dd></dl>
```

Comment: I am using this module for extra fees https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee

In the checkout page extra fees field displayed and applied in grand total everything okay, in the order page the extra fees field not visible, the grand total applied with extra fees but extra fees column not visible, any help thanks.

The only issue is extra field column not visible on backend?

Comment: I think you need to add custom row total for extra fee, like described here, e.g. https://blog.magestore.com/magento-certificate-show-custom-total/ . And fetch your applied rule info from order (applie_rule_ids column in sales_flat_order table)

Comment: FYI My grand total updated along with extra fees, the only issue is the field extra Fees visible in the grand total in the frontend https://snipboard.io/fdQN52.jpg but not visible in the grand total in the backend https://snipboard.io/JGuBUL.jpg